# Find function $f(p)$ with given definition

Tags: polynomials, roots, graphing-functions, maxima-minima

For every $p \in \mathbb{R} $ we have an equation $x^3 - 3x - p = 0. $ If the equation has only one real solution let $f(p)$ be the square of this solution. Otherwise let $f(p)$ be the product of the smallest and largest solutions of this equation.

(a) Find the minimum value of $f(p)$.

(b) Approximately sketch $f(p)$.

My work so far:

I solved task (a) by showing that there are three real solutions if $|p| \leq 2$ (the extremes of polynomial $x^3 - 3x$) and then using Vieta's formulas to show that $f(p) = x^2 - 3$ if there are three real solutions. If there is only one real solution $f(p)$ is always positive, so the minimum value of $f(p)$ is $-3$.

I'm having issues with task (b) as I can't figure out the shape of $f(p)$ on the interval where there is only one real solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the range where there is only one real solution, we have $p = x^3 - 3x$ and $f(p) = x^2$.

This gives us an equation $p^2 = x^2(x^2 - 3)^2 = f(p)(f(p) - 3)^2$, i.e. the point $(u, v) = (f(p), p)$ lies on the curve defined by $v^2 = u^3 - 6u^2 + 9u$.

The last curve is an [elliptic curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve). See the linked page for some pictures showing the shapes of elliptic curves.

Comment: I don't understand, why do you have $(f(p),p)$? Is not that reversed? We have $p$ and we are searching for $f(p)$.

Comment: @Aqua I used $(f(p), p)$ because usually people draw elliptic curves which are given by equations of the form $y^2 = f(x)$ where $f$ is a degree $3$ polynomial. This is e.g. the case in the linked wiki page. To get back to $(p, f(p))$, just mirror the picture with respect to the diagonal $y = x$.

Comment: OK, thanks. I didn't know for elliptic curves.